# State update doesn't trigger rerender in conditional rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

My component roughly looks like this:

```
import useCustomHook from "./hooks";

const Test = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useCustomHook("example-key", {ready: false});
    return (
        data.ready ?
        <>
            {console.log("data is ready");}
            <ComponentA />
        </> :
        <>
            {console.log("data is not ready");}
            <ComponentB />
        </>
    )
}
```

`useCustomHook` is helper hook that pulls from `AsyncStorage` for my native application, so it has a slight delay. **When I run this, I see the console logs "data is not ready" followed by "data is ready", but I only see ComponentB render, and never ComponentA.**

If it's helpful, the custom hook looks like this. It basically just serializes the JSON into a string for storage.

```
export default (key, initialValue) => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const populateStoredValue = async () => {
      const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (storedData !== null) {
        setStoredValue(JSON.parse(storedData))
      }
    }
    populateStoredValue()
  }, [initialValue, key]);

  const setValue = async (value) => {
    const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    setStoredValue(valueToStore);
  }

  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

Anyone have ideas on what might be happening here?

Thanks!

small PS: I also see the warning `Sending "onAnimatedValueUpdate" with no listeners registered.`, which seems like it's a `react-navigation` thing that's unrelated. But just wanted to put that here.

Comment: Can you edit the thread with the helper code please

Comment: sure, will edit!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as your **key** param in custom hook is undefined so data will never be set. Pass the key to the custom hook as the prop.

Secondly, you need to update your condition to check if data is present or not, assuming **ready** property exist on data after set, like this:

```
import useCustomHook from "./hooks";

const Test = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useCustomHook(/* Add key here */);
    return (
        data && data.ready ?
        <>
            console.log("data is ready");
            <ComponentA />
        </> :
        <>
            console.log("data is not ready");
            <ComponentB />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't originally planning on putting the actual hook code up so I didn't fill the correct call in, but in my actual code I do pass the key to the custom hook. I went ahead and added the check for data just now and get the same behavior. I'll edit the question to reflect the correct hook call, good catch!

Comment: also, the console logs are correct so I think the data is getting retrieved correctly, it's just not re-rendering

Comment: Can you also share the **populateStoredValue** function

Comment: Also include the log here

Comment: the populate stored value function is in the code I shared (defined inside the hook). The logs are "data is not ready" followed by "data is ready".

Comment: Then it seems that the actual issue is with the **ComponentA** which isn't rendering properly.

Comment: I can actually replace the componentA/B section with just `<Text>{data.ready}</Text>` and it only shows `false`, maybe that's a helpful piece of info here too